# How to Output HTML tags in do_shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, html

i want to output html tags in do_shortcode(); function

`<?php echo do_shortcode($content); ?>`

is it possible? thx!

Comment: Hi. isn't this `<?php echo '<html/>'; ?>` really doing it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

There are two ways that I can think of at this moment.

First follow what the codex says [Shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output).
Basically you just wrap your html in ob_start(); this will return the html as a string so you can echo it.

```
function my_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?> <HTML> <here> ... <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

The second way is to add your html as a string to a variable then return it later. eg.

```
function my_shortcode() {
    $output = '';
    $output.= '<html>content</html>';
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution was, and perfectly works fine for me

```
function my_function(){
    ob_start();
    echo 'Long html tag here';
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean(); 
    return  $output;
}
```